# Extract a database field via 2 combined comboboxes. Problem in the function for extracting

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

By selecting two comboboxes (combined with bind), I would like to extract the ID of a field from Table1 and insert it into Table2. I have no problems extracting a field based on a combobox, but I have problems extracting a field based on 2 comboboxes, because they are combined with each other. The problem is only **def id_rounds()** function.

I have two comboboxes: one in which I select the name of the "Tournament" and another in which I select the number of Rounds (from 1 to 38 different rounds for each tournament). To choose which tournament the tournament ID must match, I use the combobox combo_Tournaments and function def combo_tournaments; while to choose the number of the Round I use the combobox combo_Rounds and the combo_rounds function. By selecting the Tournament and / or Round, the relevant ID is also automatically entered (as well as the actual data). So each combobox puts in 2 things each, for a total of 4.

Here is the database:

```
CREATE TABLE "All_Tournament" (
    "ID_Tournament" INTEGER,
    "Tournament" TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("Tournament" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

    CREATE TABLE "All_Round" (
        "ID_Round"  INTEGER,
        "Number_Round"  INTEGER,
        "ID_Tournament" INTEGER,
        PRIMARY KEY("ID_Round" AUTOINCREMENT),
    );
```

**PROBLEM:** Currently as I wrote the code of the function **def id_rounds()**, the ID of the selected Round is saved, but without exact correspondence to the chosen Tournament in the Tournament combobox. The problem is that each Tournament is each made up of 38 different Rounds, therefore in the All_Round table the numbers from 1 to 38 are repeated several times, each corresponding to the Tournament ID. For example Serie A from 1 to 38 Round; Serie B from 1 to 38 rounds; Premier League from 1 to 38 rounds. So I would like to enter the ID of the single Round corresponding to the Tournament (in relation to the tournament), because each tournament has 1 to 38 rounds, so there are many different "1 to 38 rounds" for each tournament.

```py
#Combobox Tournament
lbl_Tournament = Label(root, text="Tournament", font=("Calibri", 11), bg="#E95420", fg="white")
lbl_Tournament.place(x=6, y=60)
combo_Tournaments = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Calibri", 11), width=30, textvariable=campionato, state="readonly")
combo_Tournaments.place(x=180, y=60)
combo_Tournaments.set("Select")
combo_Tournaments['values'] = combo_tournaments()
combo_Tournaments.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_teams)

lbl_Rounds = Label(root, text="Rounds", font=("Calibri", 11), bg="#E95420", fg="white")
lbl_Rounds.place(x=600, y=60)
combo_Rounds = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Calibri", 11), width=30, textvariable=rounds,  state="readonly") 
combo_Rounds.place(x=680, y=60)
combo_Rounds.set("Select")
combo_Rounds['values'] = combo_campionati()
combo_Tournaments.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_rounds, add=True)


def combo_tournaments():
    tournaments = combo_tournaments.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT Tournament FROM All_Tournament')
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return result

def id_tournaments():
    tournaments = combo_tournaments.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT ID_Tournament FROM All_Tournament WHERE Tournament=?',(tournaments,))
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return result[0]

def combo_rounds(event=None):
    rounds = combo_rounds.get()        
    cursor.execute('SELECT Number_Round From All_Round WHERE ID_Tournament')
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    combo_Rounds['value'] = result
    return result

#THE PROBLEM IS HERE 
def id_rounds():
    rounds = combo_rounds.get()    
    cursor.execute('SELECT ID_Round FROM All_Round WHERE Number_Round=? AND Tournament=?',(rounds, tournaments))
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return result[0]

def combo_teams(event=None):
    tournaments = combo_tournaments.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT s.Name_Teams FROM All_Teams s, All_Tournament c WHERE s.ID_Tournament=c.ID_Tournament AND c.Tournament = ?', (tournaments,))
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    combo_Teams_1['values'] = result
    combo_Teams_2['values'] = result
    return result
```

**WHAT DO I WANT TO GET?** So I would like to obtain for example that: if from the Tournament combobox I select Serie A and then Round 1, in the Results table the ID of Round 1 should be entered but corresponding to Serie A. Or, another example, if from the Tournament combobox I select Serie B and then Round 1, the ID of Round 1 should be entered in the Results table but corresponding to Serie B.

**QUESTION:** How can I fix the function def id_rounds and which inserts the number of the Round in correspondence (in relation) to the tournament? Currently I only enter the ID of the selected Round in the combobox without matching the championship chosen in the tournament combobox.

Comment: First id_tournament should be autoincrement not tournament. 2nd : In id_rounds you do not get tournament. 3rd you should select from rounds and tournament table where you join with id_tournament

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with tkinter. The question being asked seems to be more about how to use foreign keys and/or joins in sqlite.

Comment: I don't get what is the difference between `ID_Round` and `Number_Round`?

Comment: @acw1668 ID_Round is the classic ID of a record. Number_Round would be 1, 2, 3, 4 up to 38. By Number_Round, so by Round, I mean the weeks, considering that there is one round per week. Could you help me please?

Comment: @BryanOakley True you are right. But I entered tkinter because I am using it for the app, such as for the 2 comboboxes. I inserted the tkinter tag for completeness of the question, even if as you said you have nothing to do. Anyway could you help me please? The other day you were very kind: you also answered a question similar to this, so I assume that you understand the problem. Thanks

Comment: @PtitXav I thank you for the answer. I am starting out with Python. Could you show me the code of what you are recommending to me? I don't think I understand. Thanks

Comment: In fact you can do same kind select you do in combo_team.

Comment: `ID_Round` is an autoincrement field and its value is meaningless to tournament.  So I still don't get what is the actual usage of this field.

Comment: @PtitXav Can you show me how please? Excuse me, but I'm not sure I could do well. I am new to Python. Also do I have to leave, (rounds, tournaments)? Thanks

Comment: @acw1668 The logic is this: Each tournament (Tournament) consists of 20 teams...Each tournament is made up of 38 rounds (Number_Round)...Each single round (1, 2, 37, 38, etc.) is made up of 10 matches.The matches are found in All_Match.I have a combobox with which I choose the tournaments,and then I have a combobox where I choose the 38 rounds INSIDE the tournaments.I do this in order to connect and relate the tables,I would also like to save the IDs of the tournaments (all ok here) and the rounds, but the rounds corresponding to the tournaments.Look out this screenshot https://ibb.co/DMCD7Vx

Comment: @acw1668 did what I thought about for combo_rounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the modified code based on my understanding:

```py
def combo_tournaments():
    cursor.execute('SELECT Tournament FROM All_Tournament')
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return result

def combo_rounds(event=None):
    # get all Number_Round for selected tournament
    cursor.execute('''
        SELECT Number_Round From All_Round r, All_Tournament t
        WHERE r.ID_Tournament = t.ID_Tournament AND Tournament = ?''', (campionato.get(),))
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    combo_Rounds['value'] = result  # update combo_Rounds
    rounds.set('Select') # reset Rounds selection
    return result

def id_rounds(event=None):
    # get the ID_Round based on selected tournament and Number_Round
    cursor.execute('''
        SELECT ID_Round FROM All_Round r, All_Tournament t
        WHERE r.ID_Tournament = t.ID_Tournament AND Number_Round = ? AND Tournament = ?''',
        (rounds.get(), campionato.get()))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result:
        print(result[0])
        return result[0]
    return None

...

campionato = StringVar()
rounds = StringVar()

#Combobox Tournament
lbl_Tournament = Label(root, text="Tournament", font=("Calibri", 11), bg="#E95420", fg="white")
lbl_Tournament.place(x=6, y=60)
combo_Tournaments = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Calibri", 11), width=30, textvariable=campionato, state="readonly")
combo_Tournaments.place(x=180, y=60)
combo_Tournaments.set("Select")
combo_Tournaments['values'] = combo_tournaments()
combo_Tournaments.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_rounds)

lbl_Rounds = Label(root, text="Rounds", font=("Calibri", 11), bg="#E95420", fg="white")
lbl_Rounds.place(x=600, y=60)
combo_Rounds = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Calibri", 11), width=30, textvariable=rounds,  state="readonly")
combo_Rounds.place(x=680, y=60)
combo_Rounds.set("Select")
combo_Rounds.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', id_rounds)
...
```

Note that I have used the `campionato` and `rounds` (`StringVar`) to get the selected tournament and `Number_Round`.

Comment: I thank you so much. I'll try it and I'll let you know later if it's okay. Meanwhile, out of respect for all those who have commented, we also await their respect. If someone who reads wants to add something (comment or answer, go ahead). Meanwhile, thank you again

Comment: Everything works fine.Thanks.Now extract and save ID_ROUNDS.Thank you.There is one small thing wrong with combo_Tournaments.bind  and combo_Rounds.bind.I had written them a little different, for example there was also combo_teams which would be the combobox to select the teams of the match to be included in each round.I'm very tired now. I see well tomorrow (at most the day after tomorrow since there is the weekend) so I'll explain my doubt better. However, I will vote for you as the best answer, because you have solved 95% of the problem. Thank you :) See you the day after tomorrow

Comment: Thanking you again for your answer,I would like to ask you 3 simple things please: 1. In combo_Tournaments.bind you have deleted my combo_teams (it is used to choose the teams in relation to the leagues).So I need 2 things inside that bing: combo_rounds and combo_teams.Do you do this to add 2 together?('<<ComboboxSelected>>',combo_rounds, combo_teams)? 2. What is the sql method called inside def id_rounds? I would like to study it better. 3. If I didn't have ID_Tournament inside the All_Round table, would I have to use INNER JOIN to connect with All_Tournament's ID_Tournament? Thanks

Comment: Your question is asking how to get the `ID_Round` based on the selected `Tournament` and `Number_Round`, so my answer will only show the necessary changes to address the question and I think it does.

Comment: You're right, forgive me. Just tell me one thing please: if I had written the SQL code with JOIN (INNER?) in cursor.execute, would it have been the same thing? Would it still work correctly? I voted for your answer. A thousand thanks. You've been kind

Comment: My answer is the same as INNER join although I don't use the word INNER.

Comment: Why don't you use the word Inner Join? Excuse me. Knowing this is pertinent to my question . You can also answer quickly with 1, 2 or 3 staves, obviously you don't ask yourself to dwell on it. Thanks and excuse me :)